# Metro style applications are loading with messed up UI.

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

[image]

I upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate x64 to Windows 8 Pro x64, but Metro(Modern) style applications load rather odd, whats the problem?

Comment: which Anti Virus tool do you use? Disable it and check again.

Comment: I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security 2013, but i don't think its the problem, cause i did what u r saying without success lately. Am going to install a fresh copy - no upgrading, i had a doubt that something will be broken after upgrading cause i don't believe its gonna be flawless as Microsoft claims, with all the user settings, applications and personal files. To a human mind, there is no living scenario than can handle all this fuss, without a slack of error, nevertheless the last copy of windows (before upgrading) was under 1 year of brutal usage :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 is messed up regarding Windows 8 metro app loadings.

I'm pretty sure, because when I use AVG 2013, store app is fine, and I uninstalled AVG 2013, then use store, it was fine. After that I installed Kaspersky Internet Security 2013. Only then did the store crash during loading, so I uninstalled Kaspersky Internet Security 2013.

The store is now working fine again.